# Tensorflow error when building exe using cx_Freeze

Tags: python, tensorflow, installation, exe, cx-freeze

I am trying to build an exe of a program using cx_freeze. I have mentioned tensorflow in the include packages in my setup.py file but when i build it it shows the error mentioned later. I am using python 3.6 on windows 10.

I have tried uninstalling and re installing tensorflow but still I get this same error

Whenever I run python setup.py build I get an error

This is the following error I get

Thanks a lot

```html
hdf5 is not supported on this machine (please install/reinstall h5py for optimal experience)
curses is not supported on this machine (please install/reinstall curses for an optimal experience)
Scipy not supported!
running build
running build_exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 31, in <module>
    executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable("Final.py",base=base)]
  File "C:\Users\Jayesh Gupta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\dist.py", line 349, in setup
    distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "C:\Users\Jayesh Gupta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Users\Jayesh Gupta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Users\Jayesh Gupta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\Jayesh Gupta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "C:\Users\Jayesh Gupta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Users\Jayesh Gupta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\Jayesh Gupta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\dist.py", line 219, in run
    freezer.Freeze()
  File "C:\Users\Jayesh Gupta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py", line 621, in Freeze
    self.finder = self._GetModuleFinder()
  File "C:\Users\Jayesh Gupta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py", line 340, in _GetModuleFinder
    finder.IncludePackage(name)
  File "C:\Users\Jayesh Gupta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 655, in IncludePackage
    self._ImportAllSubModules(module, deferredImports)
  File "C:\Users\Jayesh Gupta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 287, in _ImportAllSubModules
    recursive)
  File "C:\Users\Jayesh Gupta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 287, in _ImportAllSubModules
    recursive)
  File "C:\Users\Jayesh Gupta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 287, in _ImportAllSubModules
    recursive)
  File "C:\Users\Jayesh Gupta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 282, in _ImportAllSubModules
    raise ImportError("No module named %r" % subModuleName)
ImportError: No module named 'tensorflow.contrib.ios_examples.benchmark.benchmark.xcodeproj'
```

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Stackoverflow! I recommend you take the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)
to know your way arround here (and earn your first badge also ;) ). Also to improve the chances of getting useful answers
please check [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and also how to create [Complete, Minimal, and Verifiable examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please show the code that gives you the problem

Comment: Can you show your setup.py script in here?

Answer (score 0):

Use Python 3.5 and Pyinstaller. It is the only solution I could get so far. CX_Freeze is not an effective solution for the builds in 3.6 (in case of some packages like tensor-flow, Scipy)